# Parsing out number from URL in bash and feeding into another bash function?

Tags: bash, shell-script, github

`https://github.com/org/repo/pull/777`

I'm trying to parse out the last number of this url in bash function 1 and pass that result into bash function 2.

I have this elementary example I have been playing with:

```
  1 pullpr() {
  2         git checkout pr/$1
  3 }
  4
  5 co() {
  6         pullpr awk -F/ '{print $7}' <<<$1
  7 }
```

I can't seem to get this to work, but I'm wanting to do this correct way.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the shell’s [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) features to extract the number:

```
url=https://github.com/org/repo/pull/777
echo "${url##*/}"
```

This will also work with positional parameters:

```
set https://github.com/org/repo/pull/777
echo "${1##*/}"
```